# Data safety form for Admob (Answer new questions about account deletion)

Tags: android, admob, ads

I want to fill Google Play data safety form. My app does not collect or share any data and I do not require users to sign in or sign up. I only use AdMob.

The only question I need to know when I select "My app does not allow users to create an account" it is enough or I need to select one off the following (that is optional)

Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? (Optional) Learn more

- Yes
- No
- No, but user data is automatically deleted within 90 days

The only question I need to know when I select "My app does not allow users to create an account" it is enough or I need to select one of the following (that is optional)

In "Understanding Google Play’s app account deletion requirements" there is this point

"If your app enables account creation, you must:

- provide users with an in-app path to delete their app accounts and associated data; and
- provide a web link resource where users can request app account deletion and associated data deletion. You have the opportunity to show users if you delete other data too."

Thank you in advance